# problem overriding generic method in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, generics, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

i'm trying to override this method from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

```
protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Callable<V> callable,RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task)
```

and i get this error:

```
incompatible types: java.util.concurrent.Callable<X> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.Callable<X>
```

referring to the line:

```
QueueItemTask t2 = new QueueItemTask(c, task);
```

from this class:

```
package test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

//import java.util.concurrent.*;                                                
import java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import test.QueueItem;

public class Queue<X extends QueueItem> extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

    @Override
    protected <X> RunnableScheduledFuture<X> decorateTask(
                                                        Callable<X> c, RunnableScheduledFuture<X> task) {
        QueueItemTask t2 = new QueueItemTask(c, task);                

        return (RunnableScheduledFuture<X>)t2;
    }

    public Queue(){
        super(1); // only one thread                                            
    }

    public class QueueItemTask
        extends FutureTask<X>
        implements RunnableScheduledFuture<X>
    {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

        private Callable<X> item;
        private RunnableScheduledFuture<X> task;

        public QueueItemTask(Callable<X> item, RunnableScheduledFuture task){
            super(item);

            this.item = item;
            this.task = task;
        }

        public X getItem(){
            return (X)this.item;
        }

        public void run() {
            task.run();
        }
       public boolean isPeriodic() {
            return task.isPeriodic();
        }
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            return task.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return task.isCancelled();
        }
        public boolean isDone() {
            return task.isDone();
        }
        public X get()
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return task.get();
        }
        public X get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            return task.get(timeout, unit);
        }
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
            return task.getDelay(unit);
        }
        public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
            return task.compareTo(o);
        }
    }

}
```

i've tried also without generics - just using QueueItem instead of X, and get basically the same error except one generic type is fully qualified, ie.

```
incompatible types: java.util.concurrent.Callable<QueueItem> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.Callable<test.QueueItem>
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: made a smaller example and luckily ran it on a different javac, which gave a much more helpful message: incompatible types: Callable<X#1> cannot be converted to Callable<X#2>
 QueueItemTask t2 = new QueueItemTask(c, task); //, task);
                                      ^
  where X#1,X#2 are type-variables:
    X#1 extends Object declared in method <X#1>decorateTask(Callable<X#1>,RunnableScheduledFuture<X#1>)
    X#2 extends QueueItem declared in class Queue

Comment: got it working now, can close this question but not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

closing this question b/c i tried a different javac that gave a more helpful error:

incompatible types: Callable cannot be converted to Callable
    QueueItemTask t2 = new QueueItemTask(c, task); //, task);
                                         ^
  where X#1,X#2 are type-variables:
    X#1 extends Object declared in method decorateTask(Callable,RunnableScheduledFuture)
    X#2 extends QueueItem declared in class Queue

Answer (score 0):

Add X type parameter to QueueItemTask class declaration and do not overwrite the V type in the `decorateTask` method with the X type:

```
import test.QueueItem;

public class Queue<X extends QueueItem> extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

  @Override
  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Callable<V> c, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
      QueueItemTask<V> t2 = new QueueItemTask<V>(c, task);                
      return t2;
  }

  public Queue() {
    super(1); // only one thread
  }

  public static class QueueItemTask<X>
      extends FutureTask<X>
      implements RunnableScheduledFuture<X> {

    private Callable<X> item;
    private RunnableScheduledFuture<X> task;

    public QueueItemTask(Callable<X> item, RunnableScheduledFuture<X> task) {
      super(item);

      this.item = item;
      this.task = task;
    }

    public X getItem() {
      return (X) this.item;
    }

    public void run() {
      task.run();
    }

    public boolean isPeriodic() {
      return task.isPeriodic();
    }

    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
      return task.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
      return task.isCancelled();
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
      return task.isDone();
    }

    public X get()
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      return task.get();
    }

    public X get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
      return task.get(timeout, unit);
    }

    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
      return task.getDelay(unit);
    }

    public int compareTo(Delayed o) {
      return task.compareTo(o);
    }
  }

}
```